# how to change existing primary key 'id' int(20) to varchar(64) UUID with existing data

Tags: mysql, primary-key, uuid

In an existing DB i have to replace primary key by UUID. The existing key is used as foreign key in many tables, due to which I am not able to change the datatype or dropping the column. Is there some way to achieve it?

Comment: Warning: Indexing is not that efficient on varchar datatype, compared to int datatype. Why do you want to do this ?

Comment: The optimal way to store a UUID would be to use `binary(16)`, [see here](https://mysqlserverteam.com/storing-uuid-values-in-mysql-tables/).  But I don't see a way around your problem, unless you want to update every table which has a relation to the table in question.

Comment: @  Madhur Bhaiya : to avoid ID conflicts, when multiple users are working on same database.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how to implement that !!

Comment: Um...just read the link I included, all the details are there.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Thanks! I checked that, but that is explaining how to do in a new table. I have existing db structure and the table has multiple references in different tables. I am not able to change the datatype or replace the column.

Comment: Then you can't do what you want.